# CSS - Keeping Navigation Tab Move In Place or Top

Tags: css

Have tweaked some coding found - would prefer the tab navigation - to keep the div in place and not flip to top and lose placement.

So when clicking on the Navigation Tab - it pops to the area and puts headers/tabs above where things are.  So basically would just like to keep the navigation clean and stationary...

Any ideas/thoughts appreciated..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="addclasskillclass.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="attachevent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="addcss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabtastic.js"></script>

<STYLE type="text/css">
    .tabset_tabs    { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; position:relative; white-space:nowrap }
    .tabset_tabs li { margin-left: 1%; padding:2px; display:inline }
    .tabset_tabs a  { 
        font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: normal;
        color:#fff ! important; 
        <cfoutput>background-color:#set.fcol#; ! important; </cfoutput>
        border:1px solid #99c; 
        text-decoration:none; 
        padding-left:7px; 
        padding-right:7px; 
        border-left-width:1px; 
        border-bottom:none 
    }
    .tabset_tabs a:hover    { color:pink ! important; background-color:#eff ! important }
    <cfoutput>
        .tabset_tabs a.active   { 
            color:fff ! important; 
            background-color:#set.bcol# ! important; 
            border-color:black; 
            border-left-width:1px; 
            cursor:default; 
            border-bottom:white; 
            padding-left:7px; 
            padding-right:7px; 
        }
    </cfoutput>

    .tabset_tabs li.firstchild a    { border-left-width:1px }

    .tabset_content { 
        margin-left:1%; 
        margin-right:1%; 
        border:1px solid black; 
        background-color:white; 
        position:relative; 
        z-index:1; 
        padding:5px; 
        display:none }
    .tabset_label   { display:none }

    .tabset_content_active  { 
        display:block;
        padding:5px; 
        <cfoutput>background-color:#set.fcol#; ! important; </cfoutput>
    }

    @media aural{
    .tabset_content,
    .tabset_label   { display:block }
    }
</style>

<ul class="tabset_tabs">
    <li><a href="#sg" class="active"><b>Signed Up</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#r"><b>Requests</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#f"><b>Finance</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#s"><b>Settings</b></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="sg" class="tabset_content">
    <br>
        Stuff Here  
    <br>
</div>
<div id="r" class="tabset_content">
    <br>
        Other Stuff Here...
    <br>
</div>
<div id="f" class="tabset_content">
    <br>
        Even More Stuff  
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Could we have the full links to the JavaScript sources, please? Or otherwise remove them from the question. Also could we please have example values for all the `<cfoutput>`'s (eg `#set.fcol#`)?

Comment: set.fcol is just a color - fff or 000 - I agree - this might be a Java thing...

Comment: Okay good to know. Ah no what I meant was, could we have the full link to "addclasskillclass.js" and the others please? If they aren't needed then just edit them out of your question :)

Comment: gk.silkea.com/ is path to java